# How do we pass an array with list of data from one file while processing second file through AWK or any other method?

Tags: perl, shell, awk, data-manipulation

I have used the following file to reach the following result:
[image]

The command that I have used to reach this result is as follows:

```
awk -F"\t" '(FNR>1)&&(NR==FNR){map[$1]=$4; next}($1 in map){$3=substr($3,2); for(i=4;i<7;i++){$i=($i*map[$1])}; print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This command works fine as long as the data in the column from Jan to Mar is same, but when the data is different, it creates problem because of `map[$1]=$4`. That is, I am only passing value of 4th column. I want to pass all the values from Jan to Mar and then multiply with corresponding value in another file.

I tried the following code:

```
awk -F"\t" '(FNR>1)&&(NR==FNR){{map[$1]=$0}; next}($1 in map){$3=substr($3,2); for(i=4;i<7;i++){split(map[$1],val);$i=($i*val[$i])}; print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Which sends the whole line and then splits it internally.
I also tried passing the array directly to the map:

```
awk -F"\t" '(FNR>1)&&(NR==FNR){split($0,val); for(i=4;i<7;i++){map[$1][$i]=val[$i]}; print map[$1][$i]; next}($1 in map){$3=substr($3,2); for(i=4;i<7;i++){$i=($i*(map[$1][$i]))}; print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

I don't mind using any other method for getting an answer to this question.I was thinking, do we have anyway of running an awk command inside another awk command?
Final Edit:

```
awk -F"\t" '(FNR>1)&&(NR==FNR){map[$1]=$0; next}($1 in map){split(map[$1],temp);$3=substr($3,2); for(i=4;i<7;i++){$i=($i*temp[i])/12}; print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This is what worked in my case.

Comment: So, given your sample data, the first line of output should be 625 twelve times? (50 x 150 / 12 = 625). Is that right?

Comment: If you reduce your example to, say, 5 columns with integer values you'll get a lot more people interested in reading your question. Right now we can't see the wood for the trees without much more effort than most people would be willing to put in.

Comment: I see you have changed all the floating point values to decimals, that helps but why not reduce the number of columns too? You say `when the data is different` - what data? different how? You say it `creates problem` - what problem? core dump, syntax error, wrong output, no output, something else? Put a little effort into trying to read what you have written without knowing what you know and then [edit] your question to clearly state your requirements and issues. You almost certainly have a very simple problem for us to solve but we don't know what it is yet!

Comment: @EdMorton I have now simplified the entire question. Please specify further, if there is a need to change it further?

Comment: You have now changed your sample input/output to images. How are we supposed to test a potential solution against an image? Read [ask] then just post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Also address my previous comment - tell us what `the data is different` means and what exactly `the problem` is.

Comment: I was having difficulty converting that data to the properly formatted text hence I used image instead. I however got the answer to my question and the code is mentioned as the comment in the answer below. I would make it a point that I would keep text available as well in further questions. Thank you for your valuable input on the question.

Answer (score 2):

your sample input/output has too much unrelated details.  I have a simplified problem which you can utilize for your case.

```
$ head file{1,2}
==> file1 <==
1 10 20 30
2 11 21 31
3 12 22 32

==> file2 <==
1 6
2 7
3 8

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} 
       $1 in a{split(a[$1],v); print $1,$2,v[2]+v[3]+v[4]}' file1 file2

1 6 60
2 7 63
3 8 66
```

your missing ingredient is not using the whole record `$0` and `split` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This helped me solve the issue.
The command is as follows:

awk -F"\t" '(FNR>1)&&(NR==FNR){map[$1]=$0; next}($1 in map){split(map[$1],temp);$3=substr($3,2); for(i=4;i<7;i++){$i=($i*temp[i])/12}; print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt

I was making a mistake of using $i inside the Array, instead of i directly for the subscript.